# popToRootViewControllerAnimated Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UINavigationController in my iPhone app controlling views in a drill-down fashion.  I have 4 viewcontrollers that I pass through before I have a "Start over" button, where I would like the action to send the user back to the beginning of the view hierarchy.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but it looks like it simply brings up a new rootviewcontroller on top of the current view controller.

Is there a way to pop the views back to the very beginning of the navigation drill down?

Any help would be great!

Many thanks,
Brett

Comment: What do you mean it looks like it simply brings up a new rootViewController? Can you navigate backwards still using the back button?

Comment: The back button brings me from the newly presented root view back to the lowest view (from before using popToRootViewControllerAnimated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something else is going on here. I use *popToRootViewControllerAnimated* in on of my apps and it does exactly what you are after.

Comment: You're right. I was trying to push a view incorrectly.  popToRootViewControllerAnimated works exactly s described. Thanks!

Comment: @Brett awesome. Glad you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to goback direction to your desired view controller then use the code bellow-

`[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3] animated:YES];`

Here 'objectAtIndex:3' is the flow position(i.e. index) of your viewControllers. For the root it would be 0.